# Split a string by a substring except for brackets

Tags: c#, regex

How can we split following by "and".

`field = "a > b and b = 0 and (f = 1 and g = 2)"`

Doing, `field.Split(" and ")` will return 4 strings, where we will have brackets inside them

```
a > b
b = 0
(f = 1 
g = 2)
```

I just want 3 strings, splitting by outer "and" :

```
a > b
b = 0
(f = 1 and g = 2)
```

Tried various Regex options as well, but no luck.

Comment: This looks like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). What is x? Are you trying to [parse expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437880/1997232) ([another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28211739/1997232))?

Comment: You can split by regex `(?!<\(.*) and `, see negative lookbehind (you can use negative lookahead the same way)

Comment: You can't parse by splitting the way you are doing it.  You loose the priority of term like multiplication/division before addition/subtraction.

Comment: @Sinatr, I am not trying to parse any expression, I just have to split them and present them in List, just need to handle split in brackets

Comment: @jdweng, I do not have any arithmetic operations to perform just splitting string with "and" excepting "and" within brackets

Comment: @АндрейСаяпин, tried with ```(?!<\(.*) and ``` too
It shows unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Precedence still applies to logic methods and you are using arithmetic operations when you use "a > b".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you have nested balanced parentheses, you can use

```cs
\s*\band\b\s* # whole word and enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
(?=           # start of a positive lookahead:   
  (?: 
    [^()]*    # 0 or more chars other than ( and )
    \((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)  # a (...) substring with nested parens support
  )*          # repeat the sequence of above two patterns 0 or more times
  [^()]*$     # 0 or more chars other than ( and ) and end of string  
)             # end of the positive lookahead
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%5cband%5cb%5cs*%0d%0a%28%3f%3d%0d%0a++%28%3f%3a%0d%0a++++%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%0d%0a++++%5c%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%5c%28%29%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%5c%29%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29%0d%0a++%29*%0d%0a++%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%24%0d%0a%29&i=a+%3e+b+and+b+%3d+0+and+%28f+%3d+1+and+%28g+%3d+2+and+j+%3d+68%29+and+v+%3d+566%29+and+a+%3e+b+and+b+%3d+0+and+%28f+%3d+1+and+g+%3d+2%29&o=x).

See a [C# snippet](https://ideone.com/gkKye1):

```cs
var text = "a > b and b = 0 and (f = 1 and (g = 2 and j = 68) and v = 566) and a > b and b = 0 and (f = 1 and g = 2)";
var pattern = @"(?x)
        var pattern = @"(?x)
\s*\band\b\s* # whole word and enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
(?=           # start of a positive lookahead:   
  (?: 
    [^()]*    # 0 or more chars other than ( and )
    \((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)  # a (...) substring with nested parens support
  )*          # repeat the sequence of above two patterns 0 or more times
  [^()]*$     # 0 or more chars other than ( and ) and end of string  
)             # end of the positive lookahead";
var results = Regex.Split(text, pattern);
```

Output:

```cs
a > b
b = 0
(f = 1 and (g = 2 and j = 68) and v = 566)
a > b
b = 0
(f = 1 and g = 2)
```